# Evaluating two 5 scale likert-scale data sets with different amount of questions

Tags: inference, likert

Can you correlate two data sets using 5 point likert scale questions that happen to have a different number of questions (one has 13, and the other 14)?

The numbers I currently have are the overall score from the 5 point likert scale questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "correlate" in this case? Are you trying to compute a correlation coefficient? If so do you have a way to 'pair up' your two different data sets (so that you're associating the same subjects for both data sets)?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare these data sets to see if they are different from each other. You have two independent data sets that may not follow a normal distribution.

This is the perfect case to use the unpaired Wilcoxon test.

In R:

```
wilcox.test(set1, set2)
```